# java initializing a field which is a class

Tags: java, class, initialization, field

sorry, c++ programmer new to java strikes again

i have this code

```
public class MainView extends View {

    static final int DRAW_LIST_SIZE=100;
    class EventDrawStuff {
        int         a;
        int         b;
        int         c;
    }
    static EventDrawStuff   m_drawList[] = new EventDrawStuff[DRAW_LIST_SIZE];

    class DrumEventDrawStuff {
        int     x;
        int     y;
    } 
    static DrumEventDrawStuff m_eventDrawStuff = new DrumEventDrawStuff();
```

the declaration of m_drawList seems to work ok, the declaration of m_eventDrawStuff doesn't compile. what's the difference, can t just be that m_drawList is an array?
i notice that if i say

```
static DrumEventDrawStuff[] m_eventDrawStuff = new DrumEventDrawStuff[1];
```

that is ok but i don't really want it to be an array of one, since its only a single thing.
i realise the way to fix the original code is to initialize m_eventDrawStuff in the constructor but that seem cumbersome and unnecessary.

perhaps i've got the wrong idea altogether, please enlighten me, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it in two way -

1. Make your inner class static
2. Create `DrumEventDrawStuff` object with the help of `MainView` object.

   `static DrumEventDrawStuff m_eventDrawStuff = new MainView().new DrumEventDrawStuff();`

Comment: thanks, i made the inner class static and it fixed the problem i asked about. however, i have another issue with the first declaration. i made EventDrawStuff static too. and the initialization code i have i guess really creates 100 pointers right, not 100 EventDrawStuff data structures as it would in c++. do i now need to go though and initialize each element in m_drawList with a new EventDrawStuff() ?

Comment: @steveh There is no pointer in java :). It will create 100 indexes  array to hold 100 references of `EventDrawStuff`.

Comment: thanks, i realize there is nothing called pointer in java but in reality m_drawList[] in my example is an array of pointers (or references if you prefer). in c/c++ i could have created an array of data structures but i guess that's not possible here.

Comment: you can. `EventDrawStuff[]` is custom data-structure's array

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you are trying to instantiate a `DrumEventDrawStuff` in a static context. `DrumEventDrawStuff` is an inner class of `MainView`, which means that each instance of `DrumEventDrawStuff` has an implicit reference to the instance of `MainView` that holds it (the "outer this").

If you make `DrumEventDrawStuff` a static class then you'll be OK because that will remove the implicit outer `this`:

```
static class DrumEventDrawStuff {
    ...
}
```

At this point you're probably wondering why the non-static `EventDrawStuff` class can be used in a static context.

The answer is that you are not actually creating any *instances* of `EventDrawStuff` when you create the array. Unlike C++, Java does not instantiate any objects when you create a new array. Thus, it's perfectly OK to statically declare and create the array of `EventDrawStuff` because it will be filled with null values.

Answer (score 0):

Since DrumEventDrawStuff is a non-static inner class here, it needs a "surrounding" instance of MainView. Without that, it cannot be instantiated.

Your array, m_drawList is only the array without instances of EventDrawStuff, otherwise you had the same problem.

If you really want to have those static fields, the classes must be static so they don't need a surrounding instance:

```
public class MainView extends View {

static final int DRAW_LIST_SIZE=100;
static class EventDrawStuff {
    int         a;
    int         b;
    int         c;
}
static EventDrawStuff   m_drawList[] = new EventDrawStuff[DRAW_LIST_SIZE];

static class DrumEventDrawStuff {
    int     x;
    int     y;
} 
static DrumEventDrawStuff m_eventDrawStuff = new DrumEventDrawStuff();
```